How to use direct system calls with NtOpenProcess?
I want to develop a trivial toolkit using direct syscalls for some of the native windows API procedures, for example I want to use NtOpenProcess to open a process and display some info related to the that process. I have a couple of conditions to follow

Use of direct syscalls
NASM assembly

Here is my initial thought
section .bss
    CI resb 16         ; Client ID (CI) - 16 bytes
    OA resb 40         ; OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES (OA) - 40 bytes
    h_process resb 8   ; Handle to opened process - 8 bytes

section .text
global main

main:
    ; Setup stack frame
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp
    sub rsp, 60h       ; Allocate 96 bytes for stack shadow

    ; -------------------------
    ; Initialize Client ID (CI)
    ; -------------------------
    mov qword [rel CI], 790h            ; Process ID set to 790h
    mov qword [rel CI + 8], 0x0         ; Thread ID set to 0

    ; -------------------------------------------
    ; Initialize OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES (OA) structure
    ; -------------------------------------------
    mov dword [rel OA], 0x30            ; Length = 0x30 (48 bytes)
    mov qword [rel OA + 8], 0x0         ; RootDirectory = NULL
    mov qword [rel OA + 16], 0x0        ; ObjectName = NULL
    mov dword [rel OA + 24], 0x0        ; Attributes = 0
    mov qword [rel OA + 32], 0x0        ; SecurityDescriptor = NULL
    mov qword [rel OA + 40], 0x0        ; SecurityQualityOfService = NULL

    ; --------------------------------
    ; Initialize process handle to 0
    ; --------------------------------
    mov qword [rel h_process], 0x0      ; h_process = NULL

    ; -----------------------------
    ; Call NtOpenProcess syscall
    ; -----------------------------
    lea rcx, [rel h_process]            ; rcx = address of h_process
    mov rdx, 1FFFFFh                    ; rdx = access mask (all permissions)
    lea r9, [rel CI]                    ; r9 = address of Client ID (CI)
    lea r8, [rel OA]                    ; r8 = address of OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES (OA)
    mov rax, 0x26                       ; rax = NtOpenProcess syscall number

This seems to compile fine but the returned status code from NtOpenProcess is 0xc000005 meaning I have an access violation.
My structures are aligned and initialized and as far as I know, I am passing all the required arguments in the right order.
